# Input 0 of layer "batch_normalization_149" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on a binary classification problem. This is my model:

```
model.run <- function(){
    model <- keras_model_sequential(input_shape=9) %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units=128,activation='relu') %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units=64, activation='relu') %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units=32, activation='relu') %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units=16, activation='relu') %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units=8, activation='relu') %>%
        layer_batch_normalization() %>%
        layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

    model %>% compile(
        loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer ='adam',
        metrics = list('accuracy'))

    callbacks <-  callback_early_stopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=min_delta,patience=patience,verbose=1)

    history <- model %>% fit(
        train[,chind],train[,gtind],
        batch_size = batch_size,
        epochs = epochs,
        callbacks = callbacks,
        validation_data =list(val[,chind],val[,gtind]),verbose = 1)

    score <- model %>% evaluate(test[,chind], test[,gtind],)
    cat('Test loss: ', score[1])
    cat('\nTest accuracy', score[2])
    ls <- list(history, score)
    save_model_tf(model, "save/my_model")
    return(ls)
}
```

The input shape of `train`, `val` and `test` is

```
num [1:182152, 1:10] 270 285 279 282 275 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "" "" "" "" ...
```

I got the following error message:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_24' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "batch_normalization_155" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_24' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
Traceback:

1. model.run()
2. model %>% fit(train[, chind], train[, gtind], batch_size = batch_size, 
 .     epochs = epochs, callbacks = callbacks, validation_data = list(val[, 
 .         chind], val[, gtind]), verbose = 1)
3. fit(., train[, chind], train[, gtind], batch_size = batch_size, 
 .     epochs = epochs, callbacks = callbacks, validation_data = list(val[, 
 .         chind], val[, gtind]), verbose = 1)
4. fit.keras.engine.training.Model(., train[, chind], train[, gtind], 
 .     batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, callbacks = callbacks, 
 .     validation_data = list(val[, chind], val[, gtind]), verbose = 1)
5. do.call(object$fit, args)
6. (structure(function (x = NULL, y = NULL, batch_size = NULL, epochs = 1L, 
 .     verbose = "auto", callbacks = NULL, validation_split = 0, 
 .     validation_data = NULL, shuffle = TRUE, class_weight = NULL, 
 .     sample_weight = NULL, initial_epoch = 0L, steps_per_epoch = NULL, 
 .     validation_steps = NULL, validation_batch_size = NULL, validation_freq = 1L, 
 .     max_queue_size = 10L, workers = 1L, use_multiprocessing = FALSE) 
 . {
 .     cl <- sys.call()
 .     cl[[1L]] <- list2
 .     call_args <- split_named_unnamed(eval(cl, parent.frame()))
 .     result <- py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)
 .     if (convert) 
 .         result <- py_to_r(result)
 .     if (is.null(result)) 
 .         invisible(result)
 .     else result
 . }, class = c("python.builtin.method", "python.builtin.object"
 . ), py_object = <environment>))(batch_size = 500L, epochs = 300L, 
 .     verbose = 1L, validation_split = 0, shuffle = TRUE, class_weight = NULL, 
 .     sample_weight = NULL, initial_epoch = 0L, x = <environment>, 
 .     y = <environment>, validation_data = <environment>, callbacks = list(
 .         <environment>, <environment>))
7. py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)
```

Could you help me to understand the error message?